# How to add regular expression in textarea tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

Recently I started working with `HTML5 tags` and I'm new to this. I am working with `textarea` tag. I want to use `regular expression` but I don't see any property for that (like `pattern`). Is it not available in `textarea` tag? if so, `.js` would be the option?

Code:

```
var regex = "^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$";

<textarea placeholder="Add Your Name or Special Instructions" title="Add Your Name or Special Instructions"
          id="WhoFor" maxlength=@specialInstructionsMaxCharLimit name="WhoFor" rows="2" cols="20">@Model.MenuItemModel.WhoFor</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 textarea element does not support the pattern attribute.

Even if you add pattern attribute, it won't work as browser will ignore it.

You are right, you need to do it with js.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks for your input.

Comment: That's the answer! I didn't notice that your trying to match in a `textarea`. It has not `pattern` attribute indeed! Sorry....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21311717/358532 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/28229685/358532 for examples of jQuery hooks to get the `pattern` attribute to work on `textarea`s.