# Validate input in comment box using html only

Tags: html

Am trying to validate the inputs for a comment box in order to accept only text, and to alert a message if the user entered number (1-0) or symbol (@ # $ % ^ & * + _ =).

is there is a way to do that in html

Comment: That's JavaScript, not HTML

Comment: First, you are asking for an HTML only answer, yet your post contains no HTML only JavaScript. Second, you haven't asked a question. What problem(s) are you encountering?

Comment: please change you question title, I think you want a solution using javascript

Comment: is there is a way to validate input in html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate pattern matching in textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643417/how-to-validate-pattern-matching-in-textarea)

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar There is no such thing as the `javascript` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex determine what is acceptable

if you need punctuation, it can be added in the brackets as well

`if(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test('a comment in the world')) {
alert("is valid alpha");
}`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8e54hhb/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function ValidatecommentForm()
{
  var comment = document.form1.comment.value;
  if(/[^a-zA-Z ]/.test(comment))
  {
    alert("please enter valid comment");
    comment.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else
    return (comment === "")?"No comment was entered.\n":"";

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Im not a javascript programmer but what i can tell you is the following:

**NEVER EVER validate content with javascript!**
Validation (latin): strong, effective, fixed.

What you would like to achieve (at least in Germany) we call "**preformat** (with interactive hint)" wich is quite different to validation because it can be deactivated by the user by disabling js. I learned to call it preformat because then it can't be confused with real validation and thats a very important difference.

If you validate using html (js) only, you can put your script into trash before even releasing it to the public. The reason is simple: JS works in the Browser of the Client, wich means anyone can change or even block (eg. noscript for firefox) your script from working. This renders your script useless. Validation of data is made because a cracker can hijack your server if you dont escape his input properly, so you should take this serios because a hijacked server can be very very expensive in no time! It can even destroy your whole life, bring you to jail and what not...

The only solution is to use a serverside solution to validate any data from the user!

Comment: I disagree with this.  You can validate with Javascript to avoid server processing delays, IF you have fallback validation on the server side.

Comment: You validate on both ends, i never trust what is sent to the server, but if the client can stop some of it, i am happy.

Comment: Validation should ALWAYS happen at the client and again at the server. It's done at the client to give honest folks immediate feedback about their mistakes and it's done at the server as well to guard against dishonest folks. This is not opinion, this is canon - it's how you do validation on the web.

Comment: Thats true. I had the misapprehension that the OP wanted to validate on clientside only.

Comment: Also i edited my post to make my intended statement more clear.