# Angular pattern validation in HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using HTML textarea in an angular 8 application. I am trying to use regex to validate the input in the textarea but unfortunatelt its not working. I am using the textarea inside a bootstrap popup and disabling the submit button if the validation fails. Unfortunately I am not using Reactive forms or template driven form. Here is my code and what I have tried:

```
<textarea id="reasonTex" rows="4" cols="64" [(ngModel)]="reason" (ngModelChange)='reasonChange()'
   [pattern]="reasonPattern" #rareason="ngModel">
</textarea>
<div *ngIf="rareason.errors.pattern"> 
    Reason not valid.
</div>
```

TS:

```
reasonPattern = "^(?!\s*$).+";
```

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643417/how-to-validate-pattern-matching-in-textarea)

Comment: What is it you want to test exactly using regex?

Comment: Hey Micheal, I want to test if the first character entered is not blank in the textarea

Comment: @YogeshMali: I've posted an answer. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**

To check if the first character of a string is not blank, you could use the expression `^\S.*$`. Expression explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/w9SQ7m/1).

**Typescript**

To evaluate a string against a Regex, you could use the [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method. It returns a boolean based on the argument passed to it.

Now that we have the regex expression and a way to test it in Typescript, you only have to obtain the text input in the `textarea`, test it against the regex expression and bind the button `[disabled]` property to it.

Component

```js
export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() name;
  textAreaValue: any;
  enableSubmit = false;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

  onKeyUp(event: any) {
    this.enableSubmit = /^\S.*$/.test(this.textAreaValue);
  }
}
```

Template

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <textarea style="background-color:white;color:black;" [(ngModel)]='textAreaValue' (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)">                             
  </textarea>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" [disabled]="!enableSubmit" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-modal-content-9ncjf3)