# How to add/remove class and re-validate after form reset?

Tags: jquery, css, validation

I found this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28229685/711479):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var errorMessage = "Please match the specified format.";

  $(this).find("textarea").on("input change propertychange", function() {

    var pattern = $(this).attr("pattern");

    if (typeof pattern !== typeof undefined && pattern !== false) {
      var patternRegex = new RegExp("^" + pattern.replace(/^\^|\$$/g, '') + "$", "g");

      hasError = !$(this).val().match(patternRegex);

      if (typeof this.setCustomValidity === "function") {
        this.setCustomValidity(hasError ? errorMessage : "");
      } else {
        $(this).toggleClass("error", !!hasError);
        $(this).toggleClass("ok", !hasError);
        if (hasError) {
          $(this).attr("title", errorMessage);
        } else {
          $(this).removeAttr("title");
        }
      }
    }

  });


  $("#reset").click(function() {
    $("#form1").reset();
    if ($('[name ="textA5"]').hasClass("error")) {
      $("#form1").toggleClass("error");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" id="form1">
  <textarea name="textA5" rows="8" cols="80" wrap="off" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9-_]{1,}$"></textarea>
  <span class="errMSG">You have an error. Check format.</span>
  <input class="buttons" type="reset" name="Reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
  <input class="buttons" type="submit" value="Save Configuration" />
</form>
```

I have two issues that I'm not able to figure out.

1. I can't figure out how to make the textarea's background turn red when in error. I have tried adding JQuery's .addClass and .css in every which manner to the code but I cannot get it to work. I would also like to toggle visibility of an error message below the textarea box.
2. I have a reset button for the form and it works but it does not clear the error state after reset. I'm assuming the form has to be re-validated after the reset. How can I make the reset button reset the form and re-validate it once the form has been reset?

Comment: In CSS set class `.error { background-color: red }` or do other nasty stuff...(with `.error`, that is). Reset button: if  `textarea` contains `.error` then `toggleClass("error")`

Comment: @Rene van der Lende - I edited the code in the OP but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: new code error: `$("#form1")[0].reset();` => 'reset' is not a function. The `textarea` gets a red border, though.

Comment: Please post some text that would be considered incorrect for testing.....

Comment: To fail validation, type any special character (e.g., =, *, %)

Comment: @Jeff I just now noticed you need span error massage too. I updated my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer as promised. Cheers and Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'error' mechanism did not get triggered properly and you called a non existent function: 'reset()'.

I moved the toggling code to a separate function so it can be called anytime, parameters:

- `element` that need toggling
- `hasError` whether in error or not (true/false)
- `msg` the error message to display

[Reset]-button will show/hide anything 'red'....
Just for testing purposes I reposition the cursor at the start of `textarea`.

**UPDATE**

As promised some changes to the original code

- I added the possibility to add a secondary error text element (`.errMSG` in your case) including some CSS to hide/show the message when the `<textarea>` has an `.error`.
- The Javascript now resets all elements that have their `.error` set (not only `<textarea>`).
- corrected a bug where an empty `<textarea>` could still trigger an error.
- added some useful comments

**Warning**: the Javascript has to be packed in a function and run not only on `document.ready()` but also after the user refreshes the page. Currently, when a `<textarea>` has an error and the user hits [F5] (refreshes the page), the error state is reset but not run against still existing data.

**UPDATE2**

Made the JS code more generic and now processes all elements that have a `[pattern]` defined. Reintroduced HTML default 'validity check' in the JS. Extended the HTML and CSS to reflect/test the changes.

```js
'use-strict';

//<!--
$( document ).ready( function() {
    var errorMessage = "Please match the specified format.";

    // find all textareas in this form and attach enventlisteners
    $( this ).find( "[pattern]" ).on( "input change propertychange", function() {

        var pattern = $( this ).attr( "pattern" );

        // when the <textarea> regex pattern 
        if(typeof pattern !== typeof undefined && pattern !== false)
        {
            var patternRegex = new RegExp( "^" + pattern.replace(/^\^|\$$/g, '') + "$", "g" );

            // (corrected emtpy) <textarea> will now be in error when only not empty && fails regex
            var hasError = (!$( this ).val() == "" &&  !$( this ).val().match( patternRegex ));

            // toggle error state for this <textara>
            toggleError(this, hasError, errorMessage);
        }
    });

    $("#reset").click(function() {
        $('.error').each(function( index ) {
            toggleError(this, false, ""); // remove error state and
            // $(this).val(""); // empty the 'value' attribute
            // [OPTIONAL] as button [type="reset"] already empties form field values
        });
        // $('[name^="textA"]')[0].focus(); // [OPTIONAL] repositions cursor to topmost
    }); 

    function toggleError(elem, hasError, msg) {
        if (typeof elem.setCustomValidity === "function") {
            elem.setCustomValidity(hasError ? msg : ""); };

        // if in error assign msg otherwise blank
        elem.setAttribute( "title", (hasError) ? msg : "" );

        // if in error add class, otherwise remove it
        (hasError) ? $(elem).addClass('error') : $(elem).removeClass('error');
    };
});
//-->
```

```css
.error              { background-color: red }
.errMSG             { display: none }
.error+.errMSG      { display: initial }

:invalid,           /* remove default red borders */
:-moz-ui-invalid    { box-shadow: none; outline: none }

/* eye-candy/demo only */
/* <textarea> can't handle 'position: relative', but <div> can */
.area-container     { position: relative; padding-bottom: 4rem }
.error+.errMSG      { position: absolute; bottom: 2rem; left: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="form1" id="form1">
    <div class="area-container">
        <textarea name="textA5" rows="8" cols="80" wrap="off" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9-_]{1,}$"></textarea>
        <span class="errMSG">You have an error. Check TEXTA5 format.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="area-container">
        <input type="text" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9-_]{1,}$">
        <span class="errMSG">You have an error. Check TEXT1 format.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="area-container">
        <textarea name="textA6" rows="8" cols="80" wrap="off" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9-_]{1,}$"></textarea>
        <span class="errMSG">You have an error. Check TEXTA6 format.</span>
    </div>        
    <div class="area-container">
        <input type="text" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9-_]{1,}$">
        <span class="errMSG">You have an error. Check TEXT2 format.</span>
    </div>
    <input class="buttons" type="reset" name="Reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
    <input class="buttons" type="submit" value="Save Configuration" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still trying to implement this into my actual form. In my HTML, I have additional span tags that contain error messages. They are `display:none` by default. Where and what code do I add to toggle visibility when validation error is triggered? I added an example to the HTML code in my OP.

Comment: @Jeff, you could use CSS `.errMSG { display: none } .error+.errMSG { display: initial }`, but that would need some extra JS as now only `name="textA5"` is targeted. But please be advised that the problem of your OP has been solved for now. I am working on solving this 2nd issue too and will post an update later, but I think it's only fair to accept either answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I really appreciate you taking the time. Unlike the original, It seems the updated form can now be submitted even when the pattern is not matched. How do you prohibit form submission if the pattern is not matched?

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that `<textarea>` don't handle `[pattern]` (at all) like `<input>` elements do (and are governed by browser/W3C built in error handling and JS function `checkValidity()` and `setCustomValidity()`). Add `<input type="text" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9-_]{1,}$">` to your HTML and you can see that mechanism at work. No JS required. Maybe I misinterpreted the `setCustomValidity` usage (and removed it). I will digg deeper into this and reintroduce it when necessary.

Comment: @Jeff It was indeed the `setCustomValidity` check I removed, so I reintroduced it. I also extended the snippet with some extra `<input with pattern>` to show that the JS checks all input elements that use a `[pattern]` (not only `<textarea>`). Checkout **update2**

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add your  `$(this).toggleClass("error", !!hasError);` inside
   your `if (typeof this.setCustomValidity` also `$(".errMSG").toggle(!!hasError);`  for error span massage (dont forget css class for .errMSG `display:none`)
2. To remove all errors and reset form use this (notice it has `.setCustomValidity('')`) as well as removing class from text area:

   `$("#reset").click(function() { if ($('[name ="textA5"]').hasClass("error")) { $('[name ="textA5"]')[0].setCustomValidity(''); $('[name ="textA5"]').removeClass("error").val(""); $(".errMSG").hide(); } });`

Working:

```js
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
  var errorMessage = "Please match the specified format.";

  $(this).find("textarea").on("input change propertychange", function() {

    var pattern = $(this).attr("pattern");

    if (typeof pattern !== typeof undefined && pattern !== false) {
      var patternRegex = new RegExp("^" + pattern.replace(/^\^|\$$/g, '') + "$", "g");

      hasError = !$(this).val().match(patternRegex);

      if (typeof this.setCustomValidity === "function") {
        this.setCustomValidity(hasError ? errorMessage : "");
        $(this).toggleClass("error", !!hasError);
        $(".errMSG").toggle(!!hasError);        
      } else {
        $(this).toggleClass("ok", !hasError);
        if (hasError) {
          $(this).attr("title", errorMessage);
        } else {
          $(this).removeAttr("title");
        }
      }
      if ($(this).val()==""){
      //console.log(true)
        $('[name ="textA5"]')[0].setCustomValidity('');
        $('[name ="textA5"]').removeClass("error").val("");
        $(".errMSG").hide();}
    }

  });


  $("#reset").click(function() {
    if ($('[name ="textA5"]').hasClass("error")) {
      $('[name ="textA5"]')[0].setCustomValidity('');
      $('[name ="textA5"]').removeClass("error").val("");
      $(".errMSG").hide();
    }
  });



});
//-->
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: red;
  outline: none;
}
.errMSG {
display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="includes/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form name="form1" id="form1">
    <textarea name="textA5" rows="8" cols="80" wrap="off" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9-_]{1,}$"></textarea>
    <span class="errMSG">You have an error. Check format.<br></span>
    <input class="buttons" type="reset" name="Reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
    <input class="buttons" type="submit" value="Save Configuration" />
  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

EDIT:
Add this if condition at end of on change event to fix issue with filed being emptied (see snippet).

```
if ($(this).val()==""){
      //console.log(true)
        $('[name ="textA5"]')[0].setCustomValidity('');
        $('[name ="textA5"]').removeClass("error").val("");
        $(".errMSG").hide();}
    }
```

Comment: Hi @ikiK, I've been looking at your last changes, just for comparison and I noticed that when the `textarea` gets emptied ( [Backspace] until it's empty again, or remove the content with [Ctrl-A,Ctrl-X] ), then the field turns red. Something is not right with the `regex` as I am experiencing the same with my solution... Removing the `value` with `.removeAttr('value')` does not solve the issue.

Comment: @RenevanderLende See last edit. I don't know where was the problem but I added the if statement that fixes that issue also.