# Fix regex for textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I found this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28229685/711479). It adds regex validation functionality to a textarea. It works but I cant figure out the correct regex to use, to do what I want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var errorMessage = "Please match the specified format.";

  $(this).find("textarea").on("input change propertychange", function() {

    var pattern = $(this).attr("pattern");

    if (typeof pattern !== typeof undefined && pattern !== false) {
      var patternRegex = new RegExp("^" + pattern.replace(/^\^|\$$/g, '') + "$", "g");

      var hasError = !$(this).val().match(patternRegex);

      if (typeof this.setCustomValidity === "function") {
        this.setCustomValidity(hasError ? errorMessage : "");
      } else {
        $(this).toggleClass("error", !!hasError);
        $(this).toggleClass("ok", !hasError);
        if (hasError) {
          $(this).attr("title", errorMessage);
        } else {
          $(this).removeAttr("title");
        }
      }
    }

  });


  $("#reset").click(function() {
    $("#form1").reset();
    if ($('[name ="textA5"]').hasClass("error")) {
      $("#form1").toggleClass("error");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" id="form1">
  <textarea name="textA5" rows="8" cols="80" wrap="off" pattern="^([A-Za-z0-9-_]{1,}\|{2}(unlimited)(\r\n|\n|\r){0,1}){1,}$"></textarea>
  <span class="errMSG">You have an error. Check format.</span>
  <input class="buttons" type="reset" name="Reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
  <input class="buttons" type="submit" value="Save Configuration" />
</form>
```

I can't get my regex to work as intended.

```
pattern="^([A-Za-z0-9-_]{1,}\|{2}(unlimited)(\r\n|\n|\r){0,1}){1,}$"
```

To keep it simple, use ***2||unlimited***, explicitly, in this example even though the regex will allow other characters.

The regex should allow only one instance of ***2||unlimited*** per line and no empty lines in the textarea.

Unfortunately, my current regex also allows ***2||unlimited2||unlimited***.

What changes should I make to the regex?

Comment: The newline is optional, you could add asserting the end of the string. `^(?:[\w-]+\|{2}unlimited(?:\r?\n|$))+$` https://regex101.com/r/LBTFUe/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pattern that you tried, you are repeating the outer group 1 or more times, and inside the group you are matching 1 or more times `[A-Za-z0-9-_]+`, then `\|{2}(unlimited)`.

Due to the repetition of the outer group and the optional newline, the pattern can match 1 or more times the `2||unlimited` pattern

---

You could start the match with `[A-Za-z0-9-_]+` or `[\w-]+` and then match the double pipe and unlimited at the end of the string.

```
^(?:[\w-]+\|{2}unlimited(?:\r?\n|$))+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/raqvkT/1)