# How do I validate a textarea? It may not be empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to add a validation to my textarea. It may not have less than, for instance, 5 characters. It needs to happen real time, and when it is empty, or below 5 chars, it should display an errormessage beneath.

HTML

```
<label for="meddelande"></label>
<textarea name="meddelande" id="meddelande" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Ditt meddelande..."></textarea>
<p>Skriv gärna något!</p>
```

I'm stuck. I got it to work for  using regEx as validation and a guide on YT. But I guess my knowledge to turn that validation into one for  is beyond me (for now...)

Comment: if e.target.value.length < 5 display errorMessage else display null

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643417/how-to-validate-pattern-matching-in-textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('#meddelande');

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  const error = document.querySelector('#error');
  error.style.display = event.target.value.length >= 4 ? "none" : "block";
});
```

```html
<label for="meddelande"></label>
<textarea name="meddelande" id="meddelande" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Ditt meddelande..."></textarea>
<p class="notice">Skriv gärna något!</p>
<p id="error">Type at least 5 characters</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can listen for the keydown press within Javascript to achieve this.

```html
<label for="meddelande"></label>
<textarea name="meddelande" id="meddelande" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Ditt meddelande..."></textarea>
<p class="notice">Skriv gärna något!</p>

<script>
const noticeElement = document.querySelector('.notice');
const textarea = document.querySelector('#meddelande');

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', validate);

function validate() {
  if (this.value < 5) {
     return noticeElement.style.display = "block";
  } 
  
  return noticeElement.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```