# Bootstrap 5 validation of textarea with custom regex pattern

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, textarea, bootstrap-5

I would like to use [Bootstrap's 5.3 validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/validation/#custom-styles) to validate a regex pattern on an optional `<textarea>`. The standard [`<textarea>` validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/validation/#supported-elements) seem to only support the `required` attribute.

I would like to use a custom regex instead. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28229685/2035207) by [@dwkd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2202489/dwkd) seems great, but I couldn't figure out how to integrate it with Bootstrap.

What I have so far works, but doesn't offer the Bootstrap custom styles:
https://jsfiddle.net/67yzqbe5/1/

```js
(() => {
      'use strict'
      const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');
      const textarea = document.querySelector('#validationCustom02');
      Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
      form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
          if (textarea.value) {
          const regex = /^(\d{4}(?:-\d{4})?(?:\n|$))+$/;
          if (!regex.test(textarea.value)) {
              document.querySelector('#rangeInvalid').style.display = 'block';
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
              return false;       
          }
          else {
              document.querySelector('#rangeInvalid').style.display = 'none';
          }
          }
          if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          }
          form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false)
      })
  })();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>

    <div>
      <label for="validationCustom01" class="form-label">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" pattern="^\w{4}$" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
    4-characheter alphanumeric only
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <label for="validationCustom02" class="form-label">Number Ranges</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" rows="4"></textarea>
      <div class="invalid-feedback" id="rangeInvalid">
    Enter a 4-digit number in each line or a 4-digit number range seperated by `-` in each line
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
          Agree to terms and conditions
    </label>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
          You must agree before submitting.
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </div>
    
  </form>
</div>
```